# Azure function scaling with event hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Per this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling

"**In the Consumption and Premium plans**, Azure Functions scales CPU and memory resources by adding more instances of the Functions host. The number of instances is determined on the number of events that trigger a function."

I am confused by above statement. Does this mean event driven scaling is not possible if azure function is hosted in App service plan? Say, I have a event hub triggered function hosted in p1v2 app service plan with customer auto scale based on CPU usage, and default instance count is 1. The event hub has 10 partitions. So, my function app will always be running with 1 instance event all event hub partitions are full of messages?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to run the function on an app Service plan you are in control regarding scaling. It will follow the custom scaling rule of your web app, meaning that if CPU usage is above the threshold the app will scale out and so will the function, it will run on all instances. So yes, event driven scaling won't happen. Only resource based scaling (CPU usage etc)

But even using one instance all partitions will be processed but as you can imagine this will be slower than having multiple instances processing the messages. When using multiple instances the function has less partitions to deal with.